# Ping my computer over wifi (RB4011 routing)

Tags: networking, switch, mikrotik

I recently got a new network switch (Mikrotik RB4011) and realized WOL from my phone (using access point - wifi router Eero) to turn on my PC no longer works. I realized that my phone is able to find the switch (192.168.88.1) but unable to find any of the devices connected to it (192.168.88.246).

I drew a quick diagram of how my network is setup. I assume it has to do with the firewall but I'm not sure what to do.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: can other devices connected to the AP ping other machines through the switch?

Comment: yes. additionally, it seems that rb4011 is not a switch, it's a router.

Comment: To debug this, I would be running a packet capture both on the router device, and the wired PC device that you're pinging. That should tell you a lot